# Matrix-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I have a problem about matrix-valued function.
Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow {\cal M}_{k \times k}$ of class $C^1$, where ${\cal M}_{k \times k}$ is the set of all $k \times k$ matrices. Define a function $g$ by 
\begin{equation}
g(x)=K\{K^Tf(x)K\}^{-1}Kf(x).
\end{equation}
Suppose $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^k}$ satisfies $g(x_0)x_0=x_0$. I'd like to obtain
\begin{equation}
\|[g(x)-g(x_0)]x_0\|\leq M\|x-x_0\|^2.
\end{equation}
for some real number $M>0$.
However, what I got is only 
\begin{equation}
\|[g(x)-g(x_0)]x_0\|\leq M\|x-x_0\|.
\end{equation}
due to the continuity of $g$. Does anyone have suggestion about this?
Thanks...

Comment: Here $K$ is a constant $k\times k$ matrix and assume $f(x)$ is invertible for each $x$

Comment: The fixed point of $g$ does not necessary exist

Comment: Sorry, I did typos. I've corrected now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As $g(x)-g(x_0)$ will contain a nonzero first-order term in general, what you want to achieve is not always possible. For example, consider
\begin{align*}
K&=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&0&-1},
\quad f\pmatrix{u\\ v\\ w} = \pmatrix{\cos u&-\sin u&0\\ \sin u&\cos u&0\\ 0&0&1},\\
g(x)&=K(K^\top f(x)K)^{-1}Kf(x)\\
&= f(x)^{-1}K^{-\top}Kf(x)\\
&=\pmatrix{\cos u&\sin u&0\\ -\sin u&\cos u&0\\ 0&0&1}
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&1&2}
\pmatrix{\cos u&-\sin u&0\\ \sin u&\cos u&0\\ 0&0&1}\\
&=\pmatrix{1&0&\sin u\\ 0&1&\cos u\\ \sin u&\cos u&2}.
\end{align*}
Let $x_0=(2\pi,0,0)^\top$. Then $g(x_0)x_0=x_0$. Let $u$ be small and 
$x=(2\pi+u,0,0)^\top$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left[g(x)-g(x_0)\right]x_0
=(g(x)-I)x_0
=\pmatrix{0\\ 0\\ 2\pi\sin u}
=\pmatrix{0\\ 0\\ 2\pi u} + O(u^2)
\end{align*}
and it is not true that $\|(g(x)-g(x_0))x_0\|=O(\|x-x_0\|^2)$.